# color specific days in different background in org agenda

Tags: org-mode

a weird question. I want to be able to color specific days in different background in the *Org-agenda* buffer (created with org-agenda-list). I want it to be lets say every Monday and Wednesday. The aim is to get a nice visual queue to not schedule meeting during theses days so i can focus on actual work :). Ideally i would like the day header and all the time slots to get a different background on these specific days.
any clue if that's possible?

Comment: Are you only referring to an `*Org Agenda*` buffer created with `org-agenda-list` -- i.e., *not* `org-tags-view`, and *not* `org-search-view`?  Are the specific days to be arbitrarily determined by the user, or programmatically determined based upon a certain criteria (if so, what)?  Will they be every Monday and Wednesday, or will they be the 1st, 8th, 9th, and 25th of *only* November, 2016?  Is it just the divider line containing the date that should change color, or is it the task itself (e.g., the title *only* of the task)?  Please give some specific thought as to the new feature request.

Comment: thx and sorry for not being more clear, i edited the original post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a custom function, set with the built-in variable `org-agenda-day-face-function`, that controls the colors of the date header in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer generated by calling `org-agenda-list`.  In the context of the function `calendar-day-of-week`, Monday is `1` and Wednesday is `3`.

If another forum participant would like to tackle the entries that appear underneath this date header, please feel free to write up an alternative answer.

```lisp
(defun my-org-agenda-get-day-face-fn (date)
"Return the face DATE should be displayed with."
  (let ((day-of-week (calendar-day-of-week date)))
    (cond
      ((or (= day-of-week 1) (= day-of-week 3))
        '(:background "red"))
      ((org-agenda-todayp date)
        'org-agenda-date-today)
      ((member day-of-week org-agenda-weekend-days)
        'org-agenda-date-weekend)
      (t 'org-agenda-date))))

(setq org-agenda-day-face-function 'my-org-agenda-get-day-face-fn)
```

Comment: thx that already an cool improvment :)