# Mark vacation days

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm looking for a way to mark vacation days in my agenda view. This would probably be triggered best by category (so when a header is marked as a vacation).

I found [this post](https://julien.danjou.info/org-mode-and-holidays/) which is getting quite old, and he says it has been implemented into Emacs but I can't see it anywhere.

Does anyone know where I start getting something like this working? Programming is not my strong suit.

Comment: You can use the diary file `(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)`; or you can create a custom sexp in your agenda file; or you can create individual entries or a span in your agenda file; or, you can hack the code (which as you said, may be the most difficult option).  Which do you prefer?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with any of these solutions:
diary - I know it exists and it has good implementations (like remember birthdays etc) but Org-mode takes care of that for me, so I don't use it and don't have a diary file. 
Custom sexp - what do you mean by that? a custom search? that would bring colors? I haven't seen anything like that. 
individual entries -- that do what? how do you get them to color? and hacking the code.. way out of my league... :p
Which one do you think is easier? Possible the individual entries, if you can expand on that?

Comment: Here are a couple of examples from the manual:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html *and* https://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html#Weekly_002fdaily-agenda

Comment: I'm using timestamps and (to the best of my knowledge) you can't manipulate these to be in different colors. As for the dairy, I don't have a diary file. I don't understand how these links relate to the problem?

Comment: The variable cited in the original question above is `org-agenda-day-face-function`.  The doc-string for that variable says that the custom function must have one argument for the date, and the function must return a face or nil.  Here is an example of an answer that I previously wrote-up where someone wanted to colorize the date header differently for Mon./Wed.:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28923/2287  In the link to the link in the original question above, Julien Danjou provides a custom function that tests the category (which is an optional properties drawer).  `:CATEGORY: vacation`